# Python Command line Arguments: Reading Files

Tags: python, csv, command-line-arguments

I just need to clear up some things:
I have the following code:

```html
def map(csv_as_string ):
 colours = []
 file = open(csv_as_string, 'rb')
 reader = csv.reader(file)
 your_list = list(reader)
 for j in range(1, len(your_list)):
  your_list[j][6] = fix(your_list[j][6])
 N = float(most_populous(your_list, 6))
 for i in range(1, len(your_list)):
  values = []
  values.append(your_list[i][1])
  values.append( col.rgb2hex( cm.hot( float(your_list[i][6])/N ) ) )
  colours.append(values)
 return colours
```

Now csv_as_string is obviously a csv file but if I want to run my program from command line with that csv file as my first argument can I just replace it with sys.argv([0]) or before the time say csv_as_string = sys.argv([0])

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use `sys.argv[0]` you will need to use `import sys` as well

Comment: Must I put sys.argv[0] as a string or not?

Comment: Nope :) just use it as is, the argument intake from command line will be a String type.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `()` from `argv`; it's an array, and you access array elements using the `[]` brackets.